# Apple Wallet - Replace a certificate and still push updates to old cards

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, passbook, applepay, wallet

I'm generating Apple Wallet passes on a regular basis and I just got a message from Apple that my Pass Type ID certificate is about to be expired and I need to create a new one.

I know how to create a new certificate and start using it but I'm not sure what will happened to all the old passes I already created and are associated with the old certificate. I know they will still work on the users' devices but is there a way for me **to keep pushing updates to these cards even though they were generated with the old certificate?**

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a new certificate associated with the passTypeIdentifier and use it to send pushes. It will work for all your passes, old and new.